# Feynman cannot be wrong

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, estimation

Nobel laureate Richard Feynman once said that if two persons stood at arm’s length from each other and each
person had p = 1% more electrons than protons, the force of repulsion between them would be enough to lift a “weight”
equal to that of the entire Earth. He stated to carry out an order of magnitude calculation to substantiate this assertion.

I hovered on the question and did some googling. But I m not satisfied. As my calculation suggests, 6 times the repulsive force can lift such a thing! And it's possible if the avg. mass would be considered 180kg. Please make this reasonable and clarify it.

Comment: The key phrase here is "order of magnitude calculation".  I doubt even Feynman was asserting it to be a precise calculation.  It was to illustrate the relative strength of the gravitational and electromagnetic forces.  A factor of 6 is within order of magnitude range.

Comment: $60\,kg$ person mass divide by mass of single water molecule. Multiply that by $10 \times$, because each $H_2O$ molecule has approx 10 protons. Multiply by 0.1, for getting excess electron charge and by elementary charge for getting excess charge in coulombs. Then apply Coulomb's law, substituting for a distance about $2 m$. Given repulsion force divide by $m_{earth}g$. This gives me a satisfactory answer within an order of magnitude, about factor of $\approx 8 \times$. It's ok, because many unknowns here, like what is a typical "human mass", "arm length", percentage of water in human, etc.